# Alien "train" in night sky any one else seen these

Tags: star

on march 1 2020 my sister and I were out about 530am and near the big dipper stars were moving one the two one then two (* ** * **) for about 15 minutes this continues like a train moving they seem to come from nowhere and disappear we had no phone to record it was awesome this was in Bedford Virginia Someone else had to have seen this